# upvoted answers not reflecting in rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I started with 101 rep, asked a question that had 3 upvotes, answered a question that got three upvotes, and I still have 116 rep now.  The math does not seem to be adding up.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question: [How should I design my new home brewing space?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6054/how-should-i-design-my-new-home-brewing-space/6060#6060) was converted to a Community Wiki, due to it most likely spurring some interesting ideas, but there is no reasonable way to pick "the single best" answer for it.   Community wiki questions and answers do not receive reputation, which can be frustrating.

[What are community wiki posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Good to know, thanks.